# Maximize sum of list with no more than k consecutive elements from input

Tags: algorithm

I have an array of **N** numbers and I want remove only those elements from the list which when removed will create a new list where there are no more **K** numbers adjacent to each other. There can be multiple lists that  can be created with this restriction. So I just want that list in which the sum of the remaining numbers is maximum and as an output print that sum only.

The algorithm that I have come up with so far has a time complexity of O(n^2). Is it possible to get better algorithm for this problem?

[Link to the question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/billboards).

Here's my attempt:

```
int main()
{
    //Total Number of elements in the list
    int count = 6;
    //Maximum number of elements that can be together
    int maxTogether = 1;

    //The list of numbers
    int billboards[] = {4, 7, 2, 0, 8, 9};

    int maxSum = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k<=maxTogether ; k++){
        int sum=0;
        int size= k;

        for (int i = 0; i< count; i++) {
            if(size != maxTogether){
                sum += billboards[i];
                size++;
            }else{
                size = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("%i\n", sum);
        if(sum > maxSum)
        {
            maxSum = sum;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you came up with?

Comment: Can you give an example? Your problem description is unclear.

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide an example for it?

Comment: If you look at the actual question, my answer might even be wrong :(

Comment: Search for "dynamic programming". I think it might help here.

Comment: You can also try out recursion. You can reduce the possibilities by using the fact that if you are allowed K adjacent billboards and you remove 1st and (m)th billboard (m-2 < K adjacent billboards), then the subsequent removal shall be at an index > K.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Can you give a more concrete explanation of your algorithm please?

Comment: What I mean is that there cannot be more than 2 removals within a gap of k because that would be unnecessary. I try to work out the code when I get free.

Comment: So you think it can be done with a time complexity of less than O(n^2)?

Comment: I am not getting this.  Are you trying to find the k-length adjacent sublist of a list that has the maximum sum?

Comment: @RBarryYoung This restatement might help - "Pick any number of elements from an array with no more than k consecutive elements picked. Maximize the sum of the picked elements."

Answer (score 2):

**The `O(NK)` [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) solution** is fairly easy:

Let `A[i]` be the best sum of the elements to the left subject to the not-`k`-consecutive constraint (assuming we're removing the `i`-th element as well).

Then we can calculate `A[i]` by looking back `K` elements:

```
A[i] = 0;
for j = 1 to k
  A[i] = max(A[i], A[i-j])
A[i] += input[i]
```

And, at the end, just look through the last `k` elements from `A`, adding the elements to the right to each and picking the best one.

But this is too slow.

**Let's do better.**

So `A[i]` finds the best from `A[i-1]`, `A[i-2]`, ..., `A[i-K+1]`, `A[i-K]`.
So `A[i+1]` finds the best from `A[i]`, `A[i-1]`, `A[i-2]`, ..., `A[i-K+1]`.

There's a lot of redundancy there - we already know the best from indices `i-1` through `i-K` because of `A[i]`'s calculation, but then we find the best of all of those except `i-K` (with `i`) again in `A[i+1]`.

So we can just store all of them in an ordered data structure and then remove `A[i-K]` and insert `A[i]`. My choice - A [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) to find the minimum, along with a [circular array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) of size `K+1` of tree nodes, so we can easily find the one we need to remove.

I swapped the problem around to make it slightly simpler - instead of finding the maximum of remaining elements, I find the minimum of removed elements and then return `total sum - removed sum`.

**High-level pseudo-code:**

```
for each i in input
  add (i + the smallest value in the BST) to the BST
  add the above node to the circular array
    if it wrapper around, remove the overridden element from the BST

// now the remaining nodes in the BST are the last k elements

return (the total sum - the smallest value in the BST)
```

**Running time:**

`O(n log k)`

**Java code:**

```
int getBestSum(int[] input, int K)
{
   Node[] array = new Node[K+1];
   TreeSet<Node> nodes = new TreeSet<Node>();
   Node n = new Node(0);
   nodes.add(n);
   array[0] = n;
   int arrPos = 0;
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i: input)
   {
      sum += i;
      Node oldNode = nodes.first();
      Node newNode = new Node(oldNode.value + i);
      arrPos = (arrPos + 1) % array.length;
      if (array[arrPos] != null)
         nodes.remove(array[arrPos]);
      array[arrPos] = newNode;
      nodes.add(newNode);
   }
   return sum - nodes.first().value;
}
```

`getBestSum(new int[]{1,2,3,1,6,10}, 2)` prints `21`, as required.

Comment: this should be the selected answer - it correctly mentions the O(nk) solution along with how to optimize it to o(nlog(k)). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let `f[i]` be the maximum total value you can get with the first i numbers, while you don't choose the last(i.e. the i-th) one. Then we have

```
f[i] = max{
           f[i-1],
           max{f[j] + sum(j + 1, i - 1) | (i - j) <= k}
          }
```

you can use a `heap`-like data structure to maintain the options and get the maximum one in `log(n)` time, keep a global `delta` or whatever, and pay attention to the range `i - j <= k`.

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm is of O(N*K) complexity.

Examine the 1st K elements (0 to K-1) of the array. There can be at most 1 gap in this region.
Reason: If there were two gaps, then there would not be any reason to have the lower (earlier gap).

```
For each index i of these K gap options, following holds true:  
 1. Sum upto i-1 is the present score of each option.  
 2. If the next gap is after a distance of d, then the options for d are (K - i) to K  

For every possible position of gap, calculate the best sum upto that position among the options.  
The latter part of the array can be traversed similarly independently from the past gap history.
```

Traverse the array further till the end.

Comment: I believe O(NK) is too slow for this particular problem (max N = max K = 10^5).

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find a way of efficiently choosing the best sum for a given gap.

Comment: @dukeling Where is that information?  I cannot find it anywhere on this page.  Also, is O(10^5 * 10^5) really a problem for the OP?  Most modern computers can do O(10^10) is under a minute.

Comment: @Dukeling oops, OK, I see the link now.  My second question still stands though..

Comment: @RBarryYoung [The time limit on HackerRank is just a few seconds](https://www.hackerrank.com/environment). Admittedly it may be possible with a very efficient implementation (depending on how many test cases there are).